# Change Password Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem in this app, it show me "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

MainActivity.class

```
        package ahmedchtn.stockmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button loginbutton;
    Button bpasschange;

    int counter = 3;
    String username_string  ;
    String password1 = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.identifer);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bpasschange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCh);
        username_string = "admin";
        if (password1 == "") {
            password1 = "admin";
        } else {
            Intent intent4 = getIntent();
            password1 = intent4.getStringExtra("oldpassw");
        }
        bpasschange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intentoldpass = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PasswordChange.class);
                intentoldpass.putExtra("oldpassw", password1);

                Intent intentpasschan = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PasswordChange.class);
                startActivity(intentpasschan);

            }
        });

        loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View view) {

                                               if (username.getText().toString().equals(username_string) &&
                                                       password.getText().toString().equals(password1)) {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                           "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                   Intent iop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagementPage.class);
                                                   startActivity(iop);


                                               } else {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                           "Wrong Entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                   counter--;
                                                   if (counter == 0) {
                                                       loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
                                                   }


                                               }
                                           }
                                       }

        );


    }
}
```

PasswordChange.class

```
    package ahmedchtn.stockmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class PasswordChange extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bchange;
    EditText oldpassword;
    EditText newpassword;
    String oldpass;
    String newpass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_change);


        bchange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChange2);
        oldpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.old_password);
        newpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_password);
        bchange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent ioldpass = getIntent();
                oldpass = ioldpass.getStringExtra("oldpassw");
                if (oldpass == (oldpassword.getText().toString())) {
                    newpass = newpassword.getText().toString();
                    Intent intentnew = new Intent(PasswordChange.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intentnew.putExtra("passnew", newpass);
                    startActivity(intentnew);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I think that the problem is with the intents..
Thanks in advance for your help !
Is there any other solutions

The logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at ahmedchtn.stockmanager.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
                      at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

Xml Codes 
activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ahmedchtn.stockmanager.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/identifer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="changer passe" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_password_change.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_password_change"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ahmedchtn.stockmanager.PasswordChange">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/old_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_old_password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_new_password" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bChange2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/confirm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/main_page" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ahmedchtn.stockmanager">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ManagementPage"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductsSearch" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductsCommand" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Editor"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProductsList" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductsList" />

        <provider
            android:name=".data.ProductProvider"
            android:authorities="ahmedchtn.stockmanager"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name=".PasswordChange"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have updated my code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132584/discussion-on-question-by-tuniprocoder-change-password-activity).

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've provided so far (NPE on line 28 of PasswordChange.class), it looks like this line is causing the issue:

```
 bchange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChange);
 bchange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 ...
```

You have a button named `bChange` in both of your layout xml files - change one of them into something unique. I highly recommend that all components should be uniquely named through the app, as that stops the possibility of an activity accidentally referencing the wrong resource.

---

Example:

**activity_password_change.xml**

```
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPasswordChange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/confirm" />
...
```

**PasswordChange.java**

```
...
bchange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPasswordChange);
...
```

---

For the second issue that's arisen in `MainActivity.java`:

```
Intent intentbool = getIntent();
bmain = intentbool.getBooleanExtra("bool", bmain);
```

However, your problem here lies with line 20:

```
Boolean bmain;
```

Because you've declared a `Boolean` object rather than a `boolean` primitive (note the capital B), it is `null` by default as you've not initialised it. Change it to a primitive:

```
boolean bmain;
```

Comment: Updated my answer. You have two buttons named `bChange`, one in each layout. Change one of them to something different - every ID should be unique.

Comment: The eroor persists

Comment: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.

Comment: Is the logcat still the same? i.e. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ahmedchtn.stockmanager.PasswordChange.onCreate(PasswordChange.java:28)`?

Comment: There is an optimised solution for my problem?

Comment: That's what we're all trying to figure out. Did the app crash for the same reason as before i.e. `NullPointerException` in `PasswordChange.java:28`?

Comment: No , the only problem now I see repeated is

Comment: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't give enough detail about the crash. Can you post the updated logcat?

Comment: Oh boy, that Logcat's a bit of a mess now. No references to your app at all. Could you do me a favour and reboot your device before re-deploying your app to the device? Just in case your device has ended up in a strange state.

Comment: Michael I have changed all

Comment: Well, it solved your initial problem. Now you have a different issue in `MainActivity.class`. Will edit this answer again.

Comment: "You have a button named bChange in both of your layout xml files - change one of them into something unique." <- this only has to be unique per XML file, you can have IDs with the same name throughout your app without issues.

Comment: I have changed that button , my problem now is logically to change password and send it to MainActivity

Comment: @HuskyHuskie I didn't realise that. I only mentioned it because I've run into this issue before, which was solved when I gave the controls separate IDs.

Comment: @MichaelDodd uniqueness should only matter if you are doing something like `<include layout="..."/>`. If the layout you've defined doesn't have those then you should be in clear. There are a ton of spots in my apps with the ID of `title`, `subtitle`, etc, and we don't run into issues with the exception of when you using includes.

Comment: I deleted the boolean

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined PasswordChange.class in your `Manifest.xml` file.

An example would be `<activity android:name=".PasswordChange"/>`. That's the most common reason for an app to crash when going to a new activity.

Comment: The app Crushed from the beginning without opening

Comment: @tuniprocoder, which is why this may be a viable solution. Can you post your `manifest.xml`?